# Do non-humanoid farm animals / cattle exist in Usagi Yojimbo's comics?

Tags: miyamoto-usagi

Given that in the comic Usagi Yojimbo some animals are humanoid and some are not, and that the split is somewhat arbitrary, I wonder what about the diet of Usagi's world, and about whether cattle exists at all.

We see  Usagi riding horses (e.g. battle of Adachigahara, his first appearance ever), and we also see him eating sushi (and there are no humanoid fish that I can recall, but I haven't read every comic). However, most animals that would be farm/edible animals in the real world seem to be sentient humanoids in the comic (e.g. pigs, boars, sheep, goats).

Is there any indication of what "people" in his world eat besides vegetables? Are they all pescetarians? Do they eat the *tokage* (the little dinosaur lizards)?

Are there farm animals or cattle ever shown in any of the comics?

Comment: Note: of course the answer could be "it's just a fantasy comic, don't think too hard about it", but Stan Sakai invested a lot of effort into making this a version of feudal Japan very close to at least the "chanbara" tradition, and there are plenty of references to battles and events from Japan's real history and folklore. It's not simply animals with swords.

Comment: The TV Tropes entry notes that "Horses, lizards (tokage), birds, fish, and insects" are non-humanoid.

Comment: Also mentioned that *tokage* are "eaten but only as a last resort".

Comment: Lastly, mentioned that early issues included humanoid horses (as well as lizards and frogs) and Lord Noriyuki having a non-humanoid dog as a pet.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots wow, you're right about the pet dog -- I just read the story! (My question was sparked by my getting the collected Fantagraphics issues). Cannot remember humanoid horses, though. If they are possible, then maybe there are pigs and goats that are cattle? Weird!

Comment: I suspect that, much like Lord Hikiji being human, it's all artifacts of Stan not having completely plotted everything out (apparently, he originally intended a later graphic novel to show how humanity took over Japan and erased the history of anthropomorphs as "mythological creatures" but has since changed his mind).